# How wide is my TextBlock after creating it?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, width

I use a ListBox in a C#, WPF project. It works. Then I Tried to give the ListBox Items a individual Background. I failed. Now I make a `TextBlock` first, give them a individual Background and then I put it into the ListBox. It works fine but my problem is that every single line in the Listbox have their own width. I would like have that every ListBox Item has the same largest width. I tried to ask for the width when i created the TextBlock but at this time the `width=NaN` and the `actualWidth=0`.

I tried to read all ListBox Items widths with a `Button Click` Event and it worked.

What do i have to do so that I can do it in the same function as I filled the ListBox?

I would like that every Listbox has the same largest width.
At this Point each ListBox Item has its own width depending on the text.

Comment: There are better ways of colouring items in a `ListBox` than setting the `Background` of `TextBlocks`. What did you try?

Comment: As @mm8 said, there are better ways than the one you are currently trying. What are you actually trying? Are you trying to give each item a unique background color or are you trying to change the color when something in particular happens?

Comment: Tell me one way to color a ListBox.Item individuell? I did nott find a working way!